# Applications on Anaconda Navigator(Jupyter Lab & Jupyter notebook) not launching

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I woke up today trying to launch jupyter notebook and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 41, in 
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in 
from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in 
from jinja2 import nodes
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in 
from jinja2.utils import Markup
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 642, in 
from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

I've used this software for 2 years and have never seen this error. All anaconda applications bring out one error or the other.

Also getting errors when I try to run jupyter lab.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 14, in 
from notebook.base.handlers import (
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 29, in 
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in 
from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in 
from jinja2 import nodes
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in 
from jinja2.utils import Markup
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 642, in 
from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 5, in 
from jupyterlab.labapp import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 14, in 
from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .app import LabServerApp
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 9, in 
from .server import ServerApp
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 26, in 
from jupyter_server.base.handlers import ( # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server'
```

Comment: `soft_unicode` was removed in later versions of `markupsafe`. So it's probably some version incompatibility issue. Can you please list all the packages installed in your environment? Since you are using conda, in order to do so, you can activate your environment, and in the terminal type `conda list`, then update the answer with the output. This will list all the packages installed, with their version. As for why you're getting this error now... perhaps you installed something new recently and other stuff got updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my anaconda navigator.